# Why don't phage vectors lyse mammalian cells?

Tags: cell-biology, bacteriophage

I have read many articles on bacteriophages (like the lambda phage<sup>[1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2063594/#!po=64.0625)</sup>) being used for transferring genes into mammalian cells, but none of them mention any sort of lysis of the cells even though in bacteria, lysis would occur. Of course, killing the cell would beat the purpose of the gene transfer, but why doesn't the bacteriophage kill the mammalian cells? Has there been any research on lysis of the mammalian cells with phages?

Comment: Lambda phage undergoes lysogenic cycle where host cell is not lysed immediately, it becomes a prophage and divides along the host cell. It causes lysis when exposed to UV or some other chemicals.

Comment: @JM97 are there any bacteriophages that do lyse immediately?

Answer (score 3):

> why doesn't the bacteriophage kill the mammalian cells?

Phage are molecularly equipped to infect only their bacterial hosts. Consider the barriers that a phage needs to overcome in order to replicate and lyse a eukaryotic cell:

1. The phage needs to get its genetic material into the cell, whose membrane has a vastly different lipid and protein composition compared to a bacterial cell.
2. The phage genetic material (assuming DNA) needs to translocate to the nucleus. There's no cytoplasmic RNA polymerase to carry out transcription.
3. The phage DNA needs to be bound by nuclear RNA polymerase. Bacterial/phage promoters have different motifs than eukaryotic promoters and will likely not be bound the eukaryotic transcription initiation complex.
4. The phage transcripts need to be translated, and the viral proteins need to self-assemble to produce new viral particles.

Under normal conditions, phage λ can carry out none of these steps in mammalian cells, save instances of cytosolic import via energy-independent endocytic mechanisms which may incidentally overcome barrier #1.<sup>**1**</sup>

In the linked paper,<sup>**2**</sup> highly modified versions of phage λ are used to deliver a construct encoding firefly luciferase (luc) into mouse cells *in vivo* and human K562-α<sub>v</sub>β<sub>3</sub> cells *in vitro*. These λ variants contain recombinant components from mammalian viruses that help them to perform the desired functions in mammalian cells:

- A high-affinity α<sub>v</sub>β<sub>3</sub> integrin binding protein (3JCLI4), engineered from human FNfn10 for enhanced binding and endocytosis into α<sub>v</sub>β<sub>3</sub>-positive cells.<sup>**3**</sup> This addresses barrier #1.
- A domain from the HIV-1 Tat protein fused to λ capsid protein gpD enhances mammalian cell entry <sup>**4**</sup> and permits nuclear translocation.<sup>**5**</sup> This addresses barriers #1 and #2.
- A reporter gene cassette for luc expression driven by a human cytomegalovirus
  promoter (CMV) that can serve as a site of transcription initiation by mammalian RNA polymerase II. This addresses barrier #3. Further, this construct is made such that only genes directly regulated by the CMV promoter are transcribed when "infecting" the mammalian host,<sup>**4**</sup> so only luc is expressed and not the full repertoire of phage genes.
- It's not entirely clear from the text of the linked study whether this is true of their λ variants, but the original paper describing the λ lysogen they utilize <sup>**4**</sup> includes gpD constructs fused with integrin-binding peptide RDG, the heparin-binding domain of vitronectin, and the nuclear localization signal of simian virus 40 T antigen, each of which serve to enhance λ entry into mammalian cells and/or nuclear translocation.

Moreover, WT λ produces [holins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_holin_family) and [endolysins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysin) to permeabilize the host cell wall in the final stage of lytic infection.<sup>**6**</sup> Even if they were expressed in mammalian cells, these proteins are evolved to degrade bacterial cell walls, not eukaryotic cell membranes.

All of this to say that bacteriophage lack the molecular machinery to infect and replicate in mammalian cells, and that even phage that have been engineered to enter mammalian cells lack the components to engage in productive infection.

---

**References**

1. Huh H, Wong S, St Jean J, Slavcev R. Bacteriophage interactions with mammalian tissue: Therapeutic applications. *Adv Drug Deliv Rev*. 2019 May;145:4-17.
2. Lankes HA, Zanghi CN, Santos K, Capella C, Duke CM, Dewhurst S. *In vivo* gene delivery and expression by bacteriophage lambda vectors. *J Appl Microbiol*. 2007 May;102(5):1337-49.
3. Richards J, Miller M, Abend J, Koide A, Koide S, Dewhurst S. Engineered fibronectin type III domain with a RGDWXE sequence binds with enhanced affinity and specificity to human alphavbeta3 integrin. *J Mol Biol*. 2003 Mar 7;326(5):1475-88.
4. Eguchi A, Akuta T, Okuyama H, Senda T, Yokoi H, Inokuchi H, Fujita S, Hayakawa T, Takeda K, Hasegawa M, Nakanishi M. Protein transduction domain of HIV-1 Tat protein promotes efficient delivery of DNA into mammalian cells. *J Biol Chem*. 2001 Jul 13;276(28):26204-10.
5. Vivès E, Brodin P, Lebleu B. A truncated HIV-1 Tat protein basic domain rapidly translocates through the plasma membrane and accumulates in the cell nucleus. *J Biol Chem*. 1997 Jun 20;272(25):16010-7.
6. Young I, Wang I, Roof WD. Phages will out: strategies of host cell lysis. *Trends Microbiol*. 2000 Mar;8(3):120-8.